# UITapGestureRecognizer cancels out didSelectRowAtIndexPath in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've subclassed `UITableViewCell` and inside the class I've added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` (which fires a method called `animateCell`) to the `contentView`.

What I'm trying to do: When the user taps a cell, `animateCell` is called (which works), but I also want `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to be called so that I can add the selected object from the table's source-array into another array.

What I've noticed is that having the `UITapGestureRecognizer` cancels out `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Is there any way I can have both at the same time?

Comment: Why do you need to use a subclass? Why can't you animate the cell from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: It's easier as I've got a lot of additional table view controllers I'm pushing onto the stack (of the navigation controller) and each one needs to be able to do the same animation. I'm still rather new to this so if you have suggestions please do say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hackish, but you can try creating a property in your `UITableViewCell` subclass that holds a pointer back to your `UITableViewController`. Then from your gesture recognizer you could do something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewController.tableView indexPathForCell:self];
[self.tableViewController tableView:self.tableViewController.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: That's a neat idea. I've tried it but I'm getting an error on the second line `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not found`

Comment: This solution is superb. Just a question: performance-wise, which is better? To implement the above solution, or to perform the animation in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (even if it is more work)?

Comment: I don't think there should be any difference in performance. Either one is fine.